# How to make selection content an attribute for a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

I am having a hard time even formulating the question I want to be answered, so here's my situation:

I'm trying to make a simple stock market plotter tool using an existing database I populate elsewhere. My app already has a nice and dynamic plotter that works with any database, but it expects data in a certain way. So say my model (database) looks like this:

```
Stock:

|___ticker___|___open___|___close___|___date___|
|    aapl    |   100    |   101     | 1/1/11   |
|    aapl    |   101    |   102     | 1/2/11   |
|    goog    |   500    |   450     | 1/1/11   |
|    goog    |   450    |   451     | 1/2/11   |
...
```

My plotter routines work off of class attributes (I think thats the terminology), which correspond to columns in the database.

I can select all the data corresponding to `'aapl'`, and easily plot the `open` and `close` versus `date` since my model has said attributues.

```
@stock = Stock.select_by_ticker('aapl')
>> @stock.open  #=> 100 ...
>> @stock.close #=> 101 ...
>> @stock.date  #= 1/1/11 ...
```

so the attributes would be

```
{open, close, date}
```

But if I want to compare say the closing price for different stocks, I need attributes pertaining to each stock. So basically I want to end up with a model with ticker names as attributes, each corresponding to that ticker's hunk in the database. Using easy to build scopes, I want something like:

```
@stock = Stock.select_close_by_ticker('aapl','goog')
```

attributes are:

```
{aapl, goog, date}
```

where aapl and goog contain the closing price data for just that ticker. I can run multiple database queries if I need to, for now I just want to be able to sort my data into this form. Also, it must be completely dynamic, so I can't hardcode `'aapl'`, `'goog'` and all the millions of other tickers into my model.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like:

```
stocks = ['appl', 'goog']
Stock.find(:conditions => ['ticker in (?)'], stocks)
```

work for your scenario?

Comment: That works to select the data, but the problem is that that gives you  a field of tickers. I want to make 'aapl' and 'goog' attributes of my model that each contain its corresponding datasets (think rows in a database)

Comment: Once you select the data, you can iterate over it and transform it to another data  structure. Do you want results that look like: { :aapl => 150, :goog => 100 } where the numbers are the closing price?

Comment: That may be a good idea! The hash here would act almost like the original data structure... I'll try it out

Comment: I developed something that will create a hash, but for larger or more complex datasets it becomes more complicated to implement elsewhere in the project. Everything works off of the Plot class, and creating a more complex hash complicates things further down the line. I guess if thats all I have to work with I can figure something out. I'd still like to reform the original @plot data structure.